# docker-compose: Unsupported config option for 'runtime'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvidia

Recently, I have reinstalled my Ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to run my `docker-compose.yml` using `docker-compose up --build`. And I am getting following error,

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.test: 'runtime'
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '3'
                                                                                                       
services:                                                                                              
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:11.0-base
    command: nvidia-smi
    runtime: nvidia
```

In my previous Ubuntu 20.04 it was working fine, but after new docker installation I am getting this error. Additionally, I have also installed [Nvidia Container Toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/contents.html).

Furthermore, the command `docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia nvidia/cuda:11.0-base nvidia-smi` is also working as expected.

I appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: please add `docker version` output to question

Answer (score 2):

This is highly version dependent problem.

Most of answers are in thread https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6239
It seems to work on 1.27 as both v2 and v3 compose syntaxes have been merged, but broke on 1.28 and this undocumented madness unfortunately goes on.

If you expect it to work with docker-compose, than you should probably stick with version that has been known for working with this feature for now.